# using indistinguishability obfuscation to ensure smartContract privacy

Tags: privacy

we all know the probelm of the public aspect of smart contract that harness the code privacy, do you think that  APPLYING  indistinguishability obfuscation to secure  smart contract code resolve this problem ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question that is really asking about the price of obfuscation and the benefit one can take.
While the price is depending on a smart algorithm, the benefit is depending on the *entropy* the algorithm provides.

While it is totally possible to obfuscate to a certain level, the win determines how much effort it will take to unassemble it.

There is theoretically no way to obfuscate a program perfectly. The reason is that a program must hold information and therefore also the obfuscation. It can be maximally pseudorandom.

BUT: **state channels** are an alternative to explore for your application, they can provide a high level of privacy. This is an area of exploration, but you can find many answers in this site or in other blogs.

Comment: thank you for you answer, actually, i ve found  a  post by vitalik resuming relevant privacy tools to secure smartcontract here:  [https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/15/privacy-on-the-blockchain/]  that could be helpful

Comment: a yeah, SNARKS, I remember that I asked some Bitcoin Devs how ready they think this solution is and they were optimistic. I didn't dive in but it looks too good to be true

Comment: @arwa updated link https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/15/privacy-on-the-blockchain/